# Having trouble using Angular/ creating a controller to render database results to view

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am building an application in which I am using MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, and NodeJS. When the user clicks on certain categories, it sends a GET request to my database, and I know it is working because it returns the results to the console. However, now I am trying to build the front end of the application using angular, but I am stuck trying to figure out how to use controllers and front end routes to 'catch' the returned data from database. Here is my code so far, and any thoughts or pointing in the right direction will be much appreciated!

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./app/models/modelMaterials')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + "/public/index.html");
});

// routes

app.get('/granite', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('materials').find({"material_category_id": "35"}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        res.json(results);
    });
    res.redirect('/');
    return;
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="marbleApp">
    <head>
      <title>AngularMongo</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/style.css"/>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <script src="./controllers/searchController.js"></script>
      <script src="./controllers/repeatController.js"></script>
      <script src="./app/models/modelMaterials.js"></script>
      <script src="/server.js"></script>  
      <script src="./public/js/index.js"></script>  


    </head>

    <body ng-controller='SearchCtrl'>

<!-- Category navbar; ngRepeat -->
      <div class="navbar">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper" id="gray">
            <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down" id="category-center">
              <li ng-repeat="category in categories"><a href="{{category.route}}">{{category.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

<!-- Main search bar -->
      <nav style="background-color: #d56324!important">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <form action="{{ search }}" method="GET">
            <div class="input-field">
              <input id="search" type="search" required placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
              <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
              <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <br>




<!-- Material results from category search; ngRepeat -->
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <div class="row">   
        <div class="col m3" ng-repeat="material in materials">
          <a href="/cosmicblack"><div class="card">
            <div class="card-image small">
                <img src="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <h5>{{ material.material_name }}</h5>
            </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>







      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


    </body>
  </html>
```

model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var materialSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number
    },
    material_category_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    material_name: String,
    material_original_name: String,
    material_other_names: String,
    material_description: String,
    material_online_id: String,
    material_country_of_origin: {
        type: String
    },
    main_color: {
        type: String
    },
    page_title: String,
    pattern: {
        type: String
    },
    last_update: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});


var Material = mongoose.model('Material', materialSchema);

module.exports = Material;
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module("marbleApp", []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/granite', function(response) {
    }).then(function(data) {
        res.json(data);
        $scope.materials = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of differences between how Angular's `$http` works compared to Express.

`$http.get` takes two parameters, a url and an optional config object. You've passed in a function as the config, which probably does nothing.

`$http` uses Promises while your Express code is using callbacks. One of the differences is that `Promise.then` doesn't return an error and a response in the same function, instead you need to do `Promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback)` or `Promise.then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)`. You don't need to add an `errorCallback` but if you leave it out then there's no way to know that an error has happened because Promises catch all errors.

`res.json` does not exist in the context of a Promise because that was passed into your server side callbacks by Express. So that's actually throwing an error but you didn't see because it's inside a Promise. Client side you have to use `JSON.parse` instead, however `$http` will already parse JSON responses automatically anyway.

So your client side code should look something like this:

```
$http.get('/granite')
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.materials = response.data;
  })
  .catch(/* 
    Handle a failed request, or any errors 
    thrown inside of a Promise callback.
  */);
```

The [Angular documentation on $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) has a lot more examples than this. Most client side code uses Promises rather than callbacks, so you should also read up on them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Angular uses its own Promise library but it's almost functionally identical to the native JavaScript ones.